# Cmd+` opens Finder instead of opening next app window

Tags: macos, shortcut, monterey, window-manager

I have: `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard > Menu focus next window` = `` Cmd + ` ``  (default)

But in fact, this shortcut calls Finder (next press gets focus back to the window)?
Only `` Cmd+Shift+` ``  works for this action. Setting another shortcut - works fine.

My questions:

1. Why it does not follow with the defined shortcut?
2. I assume, there is the shortcut `` Cmd + ` ``  which is set for Finder.
   Where I can find it?

P.S. There is no defined shortcut to Finder in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`. Karabiner app is off.

Comment: Settings that could influence built-in shortcuts: preferred language, region, keyboard layout.

Comment: Yeah, checked all of them -- nothing related to Finder.